# Can I selectively inhibit alias expansion with postfix?

Tags: postfix, aliases

In a sendmail configuration, I can selectively inhibit alias expansion
using a backslash as in

```
foo:        \foo, bar@example.com
foo-only:   \foo
```

The idea here being that email sent to `foo` will be delivered to `foo` and also
copied to `bar`, but email to `foo-only` will only be delivered to `foo`.

Can I mimic this with postfix `$virtual_alias_maps`?

Comment: I didn't see anything obvious for postfix after a quick spin through `aliases`, `virtual` and `tcp_map`...

Comment: Either you edit the header with header_checks, or just make it the other way round: `foo: foo-only bar@example.com`.